What is the inheritence/override concept of tenant and site collection managed property?
Search managed property is available at tenant level and site collection level.
Suppose if I create or edit a managed property at tenant level then is it applicable for all site collections?
Suppose if I create or edit a managed property at one site collection level, and then set the same managed property at tenant level then does it override the site collection level managed property?
Suppose if I create or edit a managed property at tenant level, and then set the same managed property at one site collection level then does it override the tenant level setting for this site collection?
